# Only "which git lfs" doesn't work in windows prompt

Tags: git, cmd, git-lfs

I just started to use git and git-lfs several days ago, and this problem came out. I could use any git command both in Git bash and windows cmd but "which git lfs". It works fine in Git bash but not in cmd, it said **'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**. I checked my Path variable and GIT LFS was included, so this made me really confused. Is "which git lfs" a special command only for Git bash? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`which` is a bash command.  The equivalent command in CMD.exe is `where`.  I believe PowerShell uses `which`.

In any case, these are shell commands to locate what program would be used to execute another command; they are not git commands.

I doubt `which git lfs` is what you mean. That would search for two programs: one to be executed by the `git` command and one to be executed by the `lfs` command.  But `lfs` isn't its own command - its one possible argument to `git`.  You could mean `which git-lfs` which should find the program to which `git` delegates when the subcommand `lfs` is given.

Comment: Thanks! I tried which git-lfs in cmd it still don't work but where git-lfs works pretty well.